# Função decode e (+)

Tags: sql, oracle

Problema :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resolução:

```
SELECT NOME, DECODE(COUNT(CODIGO_LIVRO),0,'NENHUM',COUNT(CODIGO_LIVRO))"NR LIVROS"
FROM AUTORES A,LIVROS L
WHERE A.CODIGO_AUTOR=L.CODIGO_AUTOR(+)
GROUP BY NOME
ORDER BY 1;
```

Tabelas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Duvida:

Porque preciso do segundo `COUNT(CODIGO_LIVRO)` dentro da função `DECODE` e o que significa o **(+)**? Se não me engano o **(+)** é um join mas não entendo como funciona e porque é necessário ali...

Comment: O operador (+) é utilizado para definir OUTER JOIN na cláusula WHERE. Vide https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries006.htm

Comment: Se pedia que os autores que não tivessem LIVROS saíssem como "nenhum" para isto foi preciso um "outer join" que no caso trás os AUTORES sem LIVROS , o DECODE é para trocar o "0" pelo "nenhum".

Comment: @Motta certo, eu entendi a utilidade do decode, só não entendi porque preciso do segundo COUNT dentro do decode, se eu tirar o ultimo COUNT as entradas diferentes de 0 ficam a NULL

Comment: a decode funciona por par de parâmetros , no caso se count for 0 retorna "nenhum"  senão count novamente , causa estranheza pois se conta duas vezes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa tarde Droopy!

O símbolo (+) indica um outer join. Como ele está ao lado do campo da tabela LIVROS, quer dizer que ele trará o registro composto do join mesmo que não haja nenhum livro daquele autor. Por exemplo, se você cadastrar o meu nome como Autor e não cadastrar nenhum livro, meu nome sairá no resultado com o total de "NENHUM". Se você tirar o "(+)" e fizer o select novamente, meu nome não sairá na seleção.

Quanto ao DECODE, pelo que entendo, ele está sendo usado apenas para não retornar 0 quando não houver livros. Quando isso acontecer ele retorna "NENHUM", mas quando ele acha algum ele apenas coloca o número.